# Total Number of Stories on the website

Tags: drupal

I have this website iloveforwards.com created using drupal.

I would like to have a block on the side that says total Number of forwards: n

the pages are created as stories.

i tried views. no luck. Pls help

-Vivek

Comment: You are definately going to need to provide more information, maybe some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [views_groupby](http://drupal.org/project/views_groupby) module to do this. It's a good module for counting up pretty much anything that you can pull together with a view.

Here's the [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/389230).

Comment: Hi Mike,

Thanks a lot. you made my day. See the output on top right. iloveforwards.com